# Rationally dependent coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$\theta=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n$ satisfies that $\{x_i\}$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb Q$, then can we find $n-1$ linearly-independent (over $\mathbb R$) $v_i \in \mathbb R^n$ ($1 \leq i \leq n-1$) which have integral coordinates and $\left\langle {{v_i},\theta } \right\rangle  = 0$ where $\left\langle {  ,} \right\rangle$ is the inner product in $\mathbb R^n$?